# How to link style.less in Asp.net Webform?

Tags: css, asp.net, less

Today I discovered less stylesheet and egor to learn it. 
But i am confuses it is showing inside inspect element `Internel Server error 500 in linking less`.

I first install it via command in nuget console 
ie

```
PM -> install-package dotless
```

and then relate the stylesheet in my header content like

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/less" 
      href="Content/style.less" />
```

Is this correct way? If not help required.

Comment: Getting started with Less -> http://lesscss.org/

Comment: @Malcoda it said download less.js and include it in script tag but when i downloaded it it is in a folder form where to find less.js

Answer (score 0):

The style you used is only recommended for debugging. You need to add the style.js script to your site, like below. You may also need to make sure your server is configured to serve `.less` files by adding the MIME type to your site configuration.

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But no, that is not the correct way for production use. Your browser has no idea what LESS is. Your browser understands CSS only. For test purposes, `less.js` is able to convert `.less` files into a usable form, but it's not recommended for production use.

Instead, the point of LESS is that it compiles to CSS. Then you provide that CSS as your stylesheet in the traditional way. The [LESS documentation](http://lesscss.org/) should help you out. As a quick example, here's how you'd compile LESS to CSS.

```
lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

In the above command, `lessc` is the compiler program. `styles.less` is your LESS sheet being passed to the compiler. The output would normally go to STD OUT and you'd see it in the console, but since we included `> styles.css` we're redirecting that STD OUT into a text file called `styles.css`.